# Can I use wildcard SNI matching with HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy, wildcard-subdomain

I'm looking around trying to find an example of HAProxy matching SNI wildcards, and my searching is bringing up similarly titled, but unrelated questions about certificates.

Specifically I need to route nonce domains for dvsni with acme / letsencyrpt.

```
frontend foo_ft_https
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    bind 0.0.0.0:443

    acl foo_app_letsencrypt req.ssl_sni -i *.acme.invalid
    use_backend foo_bk_letsencrypt if foo_app_letsencrypt

    default_backend foo_bk_default

backend foo_bk_letsencrypt
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

    server foo_srv_letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:3443

backend foo_bk_default
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

    server foo_srv_default 127.0.0.1:8443
```

Note: all arbitrary names are prefixed with 'foo_' so that the reader can easily distinguish them from keywords, directives and such.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
acl foo_app_letsencrypt req.ssl_sni -i *.acme.invalid
```

to

```
acl foo_app_letsencrypt req.ssl_sni -m end .acme.invalid
```

It's not mentioned in the official documentation
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html explicitly, but I was able to find other resources that lead me to the correct result:

- https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.1.3
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/14602

Note that if you were to try the first example, it would "work", but the "*" would be interpreted as a literal "*", not a wildcard.

Comment: Actually, you need "-m end acme.invalid", without the leading dot, otherwise https://acme.invalid doesn't work. You can just add both, -i acme.invalid and -m end .acme.invalid, and then it works reliably, with no wrong matches. But thanks anyway, that solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 4):

Even this is very old question, I would like to share this solution, because this is still among first google's results:

The solution given by CoolAJ86 doesn't work for me (it probably works for older version of HAProxy). You can instead use ssl_fc_sni_end instead of ssl_fc_sni like this:

```
use_backend apache if { ssl_fc_sni_end domain.com }
```

It will do the work!

Comment: Didn't try the other answers, but yours works! HAProxy 1.7.5